# Absolutely positioned element not rendering correctly in child template

Tags: css, django-templates, css-position

I have a form on my listing page (parent template) that consists of a text input field and a submit button. It happens to be styled with a CSS property of `position: absolute`. When I request the listing page of the app, the form is positioned correctly according to the offset properties (`top`, `right`) that have been defined in the style sheet.

However, when I request a detail page (child template), the form doesn't render correctly. The text input field disappears and the submit button shifts over to the left edge of the form. That said, the offsets are still positioning the form correctly.

I'm trying to understand what is causing the form to not render properly on the child template?

```
# index.html <--- Parent Template

{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/global.css' %}">
  </head>
  <body>
      <form class="form_style">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% for field in form %}
              {{ field }}
          {% endfor %}
          <button class="form_button" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
# detail.html <--- Child Template
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for key, value in mineral.items %}
        {% if key == 'name' %}
            <h1>{{ mineral.name }}</h1>
        {% elif key == 'image_filename'%}
            <img src="">
        {% else %}
            <p>{{ value }}</p>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

[image]

```
# styles.css

.form_style {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

.form_button {
    width: 20%;
    height: 38.2px;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the resulted html css code  from the browser view code so that we can look at it and see the issue.

Comment: if you mention template as index.html in your views, it will render only to index.html

Comment: HTML and CSS from devtools now provided. The `class=search_box` does not apply here. No code has been written as of yet.

I doubled checked the templates being passed to the views. They each have the correct template as required.

Comment: do you have a width set on the body so that the form knows it is 25% wide of what?

Comment: I did set the body's width to 100%, but I still get the same result with the input box collapsing.